# unrestorable checkpoint error when selection.AbstractCashSelection.unconsumedCashStatesForSpending - Coin selection failed

Tags: corda

whenever coin selection fails, "`unrestorable checkpoint`" exception is thrown.

I am testing out scheduled event functionality, when an IOU is created, an event is scheduled to do payment at a specific time. from the error logs (see below), whenever coin selection fails, unrestorable checkpoint" exception is thrown, but the process continues to run, retries until coin selection is successful.

The exception stack doesn't provide info on where the error could be, how can I debug this?

```
@Suspendable
    public List<StateAndRef<Cash.State>> getFunds(Set<AbstractParty> issuers, Amount<Currency> amt) {

        try {
            AbstractCashSelection db = AbstractCashSelection.Companion.getInstance( () -> {
                    try {
                        return this.serviceHub.jdbcSession().getMetaData();
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("getFunds error", e);
                    }
                });

            List<StateAndRef<Cash.State>> funds = db.unconsumedCashStatesForSpending(this.serviceHub, amt, issuers, null, this.flowRunId, new HashSet<OpaqueBytes>());
            funds.forEach(s -> {
                states.put(StateAndRefSerializer.getRef(s), s);
            });
            return funds;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new FlowException("getFunds error", e);
        }
    }
```

Error from log file:

> INFO ] 2019-07-21T20:52:07,683Z [Node thread-1]
>   IOU_nextScheduledActivity.info - com.example.iou.autopaymentImplis
>   scheduled at 2019-07-21T20:52:07.678Z,
>   flowRef=com.example.iou.autopaymentImpl {actor_id=internalShell,
>   actor_owning_identity=O=charlie, L=New York, C=US,
>   actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000002,
>   flow-id=0eebd34b-92be-4af5-a650-2d49675702c3,
>   invocation_id=35bd0d5c-ea00-4a7d-972d-ff353bb9d2ec,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:51:57.700Z, origin=internalShell,
>   session_id=13825f94-0f7c-4df7-80e2-c73511031bc7,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:51:57.304Z, thread-id=229,
>   tx_id=D0EDC810EF00AFC9E99494F2DEF50AD040F439DAE3FC554BBC7698B9DCBA6073}
>   [INFO ] 2019-07-21T20:52:07,699Z [Node thread-1]
>   corda.flow.notariseAndRecord - Recorded transaction locally
>   successfully. {actor_id=internalShell,
>   actor_owning_identity=O=charlie, L=New York, C=US,
>   actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000002,
>   flow-id=0eebd34b-92be-4af5-a650-2d49675702c3,
>   invocation_id=35bd0d5c-ea00-4a7d-972d-ff353bb9d2ec,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:51:57.700Z, origin=internalShell,
>   session_id=13825f94-0f7c-4df7-80e2-c73511031bc7,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:51:57.304Z, thread-id=229,
>   tx_id=D0EDC810EF00AFC9E99494F2DEF50AD040F439DAE3FC554BBC7698B9DCBA6073}
>   [INFO ] 2019-07-21T20:52:07,840Z [pool-6-thread-1]
>   IOU_nextScheduledActivity.info - com.example.iou.autopaymentImplis
>   scheduled at 2019-07-21T20:52:07.839Z,
>   flowRef=com.example.iou.autopaymentImpl [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:07,891Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.call - autopayment
>   is triggered by a schedulable event {fiber-id=10000003,
>   flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:07,897Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.info - flow
>   autopayment is started {fiber-id=10000003,
>   flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:07,912Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.info - autopayment
>   is completed {fiber-id=10000003,
>   flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:07,915Z [Node thread-1]
>   corda.flow.createSubflowObject - autopayment to invoke flow
>   com.charlie.iou.flows.SettleIOUInitiatorImpl {fiber-id=10000003,
>   flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:07,922Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.info - flow
>   SettleIOU startred {fiber-id=10000003,
>   flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:08,062Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.lambda$eval$3 -
>   txbuilder::build commands, cmd=Move,
>   keys=["GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyGKLLbMNy9c7hZ3XmrUEpRayxezT7VanQYX7c61RPCedL","GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyQbQ5fnon7qDegNzvJ4s71djeDtZVSfoA466yXun6CLcK","GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyV2oK18JdGAUozHXddWjBCFoMMKhMz5taj1qUyVYWBBfi"]
>   {fiber-id=10000003, flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:08,063Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.eval -
>   txbuilder::build commands, cmd=com.example.iou.SettleIOU,
>   keys=["GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyQbQ5fnon7qDegNzvJ4s71djeDtZVSfoA466yXun6CLcK","GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgySdF6Vz2jjYaaUP61nQVBgMJUAvmnhhWGA34bUwC9CaVn","GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyV2oK18JdGAUozHXddWjBCFoMMKhMz5taj1qUyVYWBBfi"]
>   {fiber-id=10000003, flow-id=c8d1be17-aa32-4a73-b031-fff2707ed877,
>   invocation_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, origin=Scheduler,
>   session_id=09dbdf92-55cb-4bcc-8ce9-5eae3103a740,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:52:07.842Z, thread-id=229} [INFO ]
>   2019-07-21T20:52:08,337Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.call - Party
>   O=bob, L=New York, C=US received the transaction.
>   {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=charlie, L=New York,
>   C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000002,
>   flow-id=0eebd34b-92be-4af5-a650-2d49675702c3,
>   invocation_id=35bd0d5c-ea00-4a7d-972d-ff353bb9d2ec,
>   invocation_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:51:57.700Z, origin=internalShell,
>   session_id=13825f94-0f7c-4df7-80e2-c73511031bc7,
>   session_timestamp=2019-07-21T20:51:57.304Z, thread-id=229,
>   tx_id=D0EDC810EF00AFC9E99494F2DEF50AD040F439DAE3FC554BBC7698B9DCBA6073}
>   [INFO ] 2019-07-21T20:52:08,338Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.call - All
>   parties received the transaction successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In our recent release of the TokenSDK 1.1, we have officially introduced the token-selection pack.

Here is the link for the binary file: https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/corda-lib/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/tokens-selection

And here is an example of how to import the dependencies to your project: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking/build.gradle#L120

And here is how you use it:

```
Pair<List<StateAndRef<FungibleToken>>, List<FungibleToken>> inputsAndOutputs =
                tokenSelection.generateMove(Arrays.asList(partyAndAmount), buyerAccount, new TokenQueryBy(), getRunId().getUuid());
```